# Remove or create 'Has a 'relationship between entities in REST

Tags: rest

I have a destination pool entity that can have many destination entities. How do I have a REST URL request to add a destination to destination pool or delete a destination from destination pool.

Right now I am using

**/destinationpool/{destinationpool-name}/add/{destination-name}** to add a destination to a destination pool

**/destinationpool/{destinationpool-name}/delete/{destination-name}** to remove a 
destination from a destination pool

Both being PUT requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to truly be RESTful, your CRUD actions should be indicated by your http verbs, not your url. I tend to place my inputs as part of the url parameters so that it mimics a standard function call in which you have the function definition and the parameters.

to create ([post vs put](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/))

```
[POST]
/destinationpool/{destinationpool-name}/destinations
(url).../destinationpool/{destinationpool-name}/destinations?destination-name=<name>
```

to delete

```
[DELETE]
/destinationpool/{destinationpool-name}/destinations
(url)..../destinationpool/{destinationpool-name}/destinations?destination-name=<name>
```

When you read the above, it is clear that you are placing something into the destinations  relation of destination pool (or deleting something from).

As a side note - names are dangerous due to uniqueness, spelling, capitalization, etc. Ids are much better.

Comment: Just to be more clear, we are not adding or deleting destinations to & from destination pool, we are just adding and removing the association between them. Destinations are not tied to destination pool. A destination can be added to multiple destination pools. Please let me know if the above still makes sense?